# Deployment of web application delegating to the fixed openam sso url

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, openam

Given I have following problem:

I have the web application which delegates sso login to [openam](https://forgerock.org/openam/)

I deploy web application, database, openam using docker-compose as docker containers

When I want to deploy it, I need to specify SSO login url as deployment property in a format:
http://OPENAM_IP_ADDRESS:PORT/openam/UI/Login

Please note port number is external to the docker network containers live in

It has to be that way because browser redirects to the openam URL I described above

This implies I need to know IP address and port beforehand, which makes the deployment process cumbersome. Especially when the number of environments I want to deploy to grows. Instead of having one deployment properties file, I have one for each environment.

I was told, reverse proxy could solve the problem where I can store a record, e.g. **openam.sso.url** and then web application can somehow be registered with reverse proxy

Is there a solution to the problem above?

Comment: Are you using an OpenAM policy agent to achieve SSO with OpenAM or the OpenAM clientSDK?

Of course you could use a fixed URL as well, no need for a http reverse-proxy server (unless you want to change TCP listen port). You just need to tell OpenAM it should handle that URL (or better HTTP host-header ) as well. Depending on cookie domains you may need to configure OpenAM accordingly,

Comment: I use open am mock (written in-house) for dev/test environments. This mock is just war application which simulates very basic sso actions and is deployed to tomcat docker container. This problem is rather more generic deployment problem, not particularly issue with openam. I just wanted to give actual example.

Comment: As long as you have full control over name resolution you can achieve this. You tagged this as openam, this suggested you want to use OpenAM ?!?